Disable generation of ALIGN directives
I use IDA for disassembly and ALIGN directives often appear in disassembly code, such as here:
                ALIGN 0x10
off_8030680     DCD 0x200261D8
dword_8030680   DCD 0x20027D2A

Is it possible to disable the creation of these directives? There are non-zero bytes behind them, and I would like to see them, for example like this:
                DCW 0xBF00
off_8030680     DCD 0x200261D8
dword_8030680   DCD 0x20027D2A


I don't think there is a specific option for that. This is done during one of the final analysis passes so you might try to switching them off during file loading (kernel options 2/3). But that would probably disable some other analyses like converting unreferenced code into code.

Yes, if you uncheck the 'Make final analysis pass' checkbox, the ALIGN directives do not appear. However, at the same time, as you said, the code, which is not referenced anywhere, remains just bytes.

Maybe it is possible to achieve what I need by writing a script for IDA? After all, it is easy to manually convert the ALIGN directive into a byte or word.

I don't know of a way to just disable creation of alignment items, but script to remove them surely can be made. Something like this (IDC, Python version can be made same way):
// unfortunately alignments cannot be found by find_data, so using this more broad one
auto ea = find_defined(0, SEARCH_DOWN);
while (ea != BADADDR) {
    if (is_align(get_flags(ea))) {
        // todo: maybe check for non-zero bytes and leave zeroes in?
        del_items(ea, DELIT_SIMPLE);
        // todo: convert it to data instead if you want it that way
    } else {
       ea = next_head(ea, BADADDR); // not an alignment, skip this item (so the script doesn't have to trudge through e.g. arrays byte by byte)
    }
    ea = find_defined(ea, SEARCH_DOWN);
}

